# Retrive xml info using java

Tags: java, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss"><title>USGS All Earthquakes, Past Week</title><updated>2020-02-26T21:28:38Z</updated><author><name>U.S. Geological Survey</name><uri>https://earthquake.usgs.gov/</uri></author><id>https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_week.atom</id><link rel="self" href="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_week.atom"/><icon>https://earthquake.usgs.gov/favicon.ico</icon>
<entry><id>urn:earthquake-usgs-gov:ci:39084495</id><title>M 0.6 - 13km WNW of Anza, CA</title><updated>2020-02-26T21:23:25.292Z</updated><link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/ci39084495"/><summary type="html"><![CDATA[<dl><dt>Time</dt><dd>2020-02-26 21:19:49 UTC</dd><dd>2020-02-26 13:19:49 -08:00 at epicenter</dd><dt>Location</dt><dd>33.602&deg;N 116.804&deg;W</dd><dt>Depth</dt><dd>4.62 km (2.87 mi)</dd></dl>]]></summary><georss:point>33.6016667 -116.8035</georss:point><georss:elev>-4620</georss:elev><category label="Age" term="Past Hour"/><category label="Magnitude" term="Magnitude 0"/><category label="Contributor" term="ci"/><category label="Author" term="ci"/></entry></feed>
```

I'm Trying to extract information from this xml, I did manage to do it but im not sure how its working, more precisely i don't understand why the value seems to be so deep in the nodes. the code im using is as follows

```
            builder = fac.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(source);
            NodeList nodeList = doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();


            for(int i=0;i < nodeList.getLength();i++){
                Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                if (node.getNodeName().equals("entry")){
                    Element element = (Element) node;
                    String nl1 = element.getElementsByTagName("georss:point").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                }
            }
```

I had expected that after getting the element by the tag i should be able to get the value right away but instead i have to go two levels deeper, can anyone explain why?

EDIT: typo

Comment: Hi, if my answer is the solution to your problem please mark it accordingly. If not, please specify what issue still exists. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are asking, why it seems to be so deeply nested. I will answer that first and then suggest three other approaches you also could consider to work with that xml in java.

**Why is it so nested**

`Element.getElementsByTagName()` returns a NodeList which contains 0-n elements. You know that you only have one but the xml-engine not. So you need to say: Give me the first element of that list (`.item(0)`).

Now you have the element `point` but you want to have its content. You are accessing the content as a child, but again: there could be multiple children (like other tags), so again you need to tell which element.

**Alternative approaches**

1. Access the content as text content: `element.getElementsByTagName("georss:point").item(0).getTextContent();`
2. Using Xpath:

   `XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
   XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
   XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//*[local-name()='point']");
   String evaluate = expr.evaluate(doc);
   System.out.println(evaluate);`

Kindly note that the xpath `//*[local-name()='point']` is not the best way. You should work with the namespaces which would require some more code.

3. Use xml to bean mapping, for example with [JAXB](https://www.javatpoint.com/jaxb-tutorial)

You should really consider this approach as it basically allows you to have Pojo objects with all content of the xml (like the age, magnitude, ...) and simply have the xml transformed in a object like this:

```
public class Entry{
    private String id;
    private String title;
    ...
    private String point;
    private String age;
    private String magnitude;
    ...
```

I hope this helps.